# why the elements are not getting spaced?

Tags: css

hey i want the 3 div to be spaced between in the website with the help of bootstrap in  the nav bar anmd i am not getting the desired results 
i want THE DIV TO BE  like this way  pls help me to solve it with bootstrap classes

`<content of div1>     <content of div2>    <content of div3>`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light d-flex justify-content-between  ">
  <div>// div 1//
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">// div 2//
  </div>
  <div>// div 3//
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's because you have a typo in your HTML. You have `<nav clss` instead of `<nav class`

Comment: You don't need to put whole content, next time you will be downvoted. Just ask question with relevant content -- that will provide fix to your answer.

Comment: Since you updated your code to fix the typo, just remove `flex-grow: 1` on your second div.

Answer (score 0):

By default `.navbar-collapse` is set to `flex-grow:1`. You need to disable this to get what you want:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light d-flex justify-content-between  ">
  <div>// div 1//
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">// div 2//
  </div>
  <div>// div 3//
  </div>
</nav>
```